# How can I switch refresh rate with Safe mode?

Tags: windows-7, display

I accidentally switched the refresh rate from 90 Hz to 60 Hz.

I can access safe mode but when I try to access Windows normally, my screen says "Out of Range".

How can I switch the refresh rate back with safe mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After booting to Safe Mode:

1. Run `msconfig.exe` (menu start, type `msconfig`)
2. Select **Boot** tab
3. Check **Base video**

   [image: Windows 7 Base Video]
4. Restart the system
5. Change the *Screen refresh rate* in *Display settings* -> *Advanced Settings* -> *Monitor* to 60 Hz.
6. Go through 1-4 steps (in Normal Mode) this time unchecking the **Base video**

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, msconfig.exe. Too bad we got it fixed wih another way.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally changed it from 60 to 90 and my monitor kept saying it was out of range sometimes seconds after login in successfully... really frustrating...
Also the fix by techraf didn't work for me.

What worked in the end was the following:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Type "regedit" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

  - If a message pops up saying "do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device" click YES.
  - A window called "Registry Editor" should show.
- Locate these three registry keys:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\ScaleFactors
  ```

  After finding them, right click on each folder and select "delete" and then "yes".

(And then reboot of course.)
Cited from [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-reset-external-monitors-settings/b3a53cef-e54f-4410-b09e-6846fa297a3f).